# cakephp Supress All Headers And ALL data

Tags: cakephp, icalendar

I am trying to create a subscribable web cal.  The file works, if I link to it directly.  But when generated out of CAKEPHP, even with a blank layout, the calendar program says the data is invalid.  I am guessing there are some hidden headers, data, something that cakephp is sending in the background.  Any way to have cakephp just send the actual file?

Any other ideas why I can't subscribe?

Comment: Try setting debug to 0 in your core.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you put `Configure::Write('debug',0);` in the action in your controller that returns the data for the calendar.  And then make sure you call a layout that ONLY has `<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>` and nothing else in it using `$this->layout = ‘yourlayout’;` in that same action in the controller.